# How to get text only from the DIV when it has child elements with text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to get the text from a parent DIV when it has child elements with text using jQuery?

```
<div id='div_1'>
  I am a DIV
  <span>
    I am a SPAN
  </span> 
</div>
```

If I was to use  $('#div_1').text(),it will give me 'I am a DIV I am a SPAN'.How do I get just the text 'I am a DIV from' div_1? Any help much appreciated,thank you.

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464647/return-node-text-non-recursive

Comment: @Silent-Penguin that's the right way of doing this, for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('#div_1').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='div_1'> 
  I am a DIV 
  <span> 
    I am a SPAN 
  </span>  
</div> 
<script> 
$(function(){ 
    $("#div_1").contents().filter('*').remove(); 
}); 
</script>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c4fb9.php

Answer (score 1):

You can access the text-node that you are looking for directly.  In your case, use the following:

```
 $('#div_1')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Every node has a list of child nodes, which may be other HTML elements, or text-nodes.  Thus, we are getting the first child (in your case a text node) and returning the `nodeValue` which will be the text itself.  Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/QCMsP/11/).

Comment: I think this is best and fastest option

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.remove()` to get rid of the HTML elements inside the `div`. [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/hj8Sy/).

And the code to go with it:

#### HTML

```
<div id='div_1'>
  I am a DIV
  <span>
    I am a SPAN
  </span> 
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = $("div#div_1").clone();
    
    div.find("*").remove();
    
    $("div#output").text(div.text());
});
```

I've made it a little more complex than it needs to be (using `.clone()`) so the `div`'s original content is preserved. If you just want to get the text and don't care about the original content, you can leave the `.clone()` out.

Comment: why so hard when it is achievable easy?

Comment: @genesis Ah nice solution there. I forgot about filter.

Comment: As crap as it may be, it still works so I'll leave it up. Thanks for the tips, however - this question has also taught me something ;-P