# I have a DOM node How do I get its text in it

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a DOM node, lets say `node` and this may have some children and has text in it. I need to get only the text from it.

I know that `node.innerHTML` gives the whole data between the tags but I don't need the child elements. This can be done using jquery once i get the node's id [How to get text only from the DIV when it has child elements with text using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063408/how-to-get-text-only-from-the-div-when-it-has-child-elements-with-text-using-jqu) But in that case I am again finding the node which is a waste of time. Right now I already have the node and I only need to get its text. I tried `node.text` but it is returning undefined value.
Please help.

Comment: @Cattla It is giving the text of innerChild also

Comment: Do you want the text-content from `node` only, or including all childrens text-content?

Comment: text only from node only not it schildren...

Comment: Well, `.innerText` would include the children's text content. http://jsbin.com/zowafigoxu/1/

Comment: Source of jquery.text: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.0.3&fn=jQuery.text

Comment: @Yoshi yeah saw that jus now

Comment: I think you'll need to traverse the node's children and concat all text-nodes *by hand*. No magic here to help you.

Comment: Ohh or can I remove all the children and then use innerText..?

Comment: @Srinath Of course, if it's ok to manipulate the parent node, that's also one way to do it.

Comment: Yeah ill clone it and then remove similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063408/how-to-get-text-only-from-the-div-when-it-has-child-elements-with-text-using-jqu

Comment: Why not using the example you gave us? You really think it's a waste of time?

Comment: Ok, I think this question is duplicate then?!

Comment: @VincentBeltman yeah This is for a chrome extension and I am traversing through a large html document to get some node when its onclick event is triggered and then going to one of its siblingNodes to get the text..so having the node and again searching for it I feel waste of time

Comment: @Yoshi Yeah may be once I found we can get text of a node by .innerText then the remaining can be done. I wasn't aware of .innerText

Comment: Did you try it out? Is it really that slow?

Comment: @VincentBeltman nah I didn't try it but I feel so for pages like facebook... am i wrong?

Comment: You'll never know until you try. Think about it. It would be around the same speed as css. They're both selectors. correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Looping over the [`.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) and grabbing the [`.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue) of the [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) should work:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo'),
    txt = '';

[].forEach.call(foo.childNodes, function (subNode) {
  if (subNode.nodeType === 3) {
    txt += subNode.nodeValue;
  }
});

console.log(txt);
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/buqid/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

`.childNodes` is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array. You cannot use array methods on them, `foo.childNodes.forEach()` would not work.

`NodeList` objects are however [*array-like*](https://shifteleven.com/articles/2007/06/28/array-like-objects-in-javascript/) objects, so we can use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to treat `foo.childNodes` as if it were a real array and call [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on it.

The callback we provide [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) checks the [`.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) of each `Node`, if it is a text node (a `Node` with a `.nodeType` of `3`) we append it's value to our output buffer.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand correctly but if you need the text for each element of the node then for JQuery you would do:

```
node.each(function (index){
console.debug($(this).text());
});
```