# Javascript querySelectorAll and :not Selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

```
<div class="classDiv">

<span id="mySpan"> TEXT 1 </span> TEXT 2

</div>
```

Using document.querySelectorAll(".classDiv")[0].textContent

Returns = TEXT 1 TEXT 2

How can i get only TEXT 2?

I tried with :not(span) without success.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this one, it's jquery but I hope you'll get the point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063408/how-to-get-text-only-from-the-div-when-it-has-child-elements-with-text-using-jqu

Answer (score 3):

There’s nothing built-in that I’m aware of, but you can add a function to extract text nodes that are direct children of an element:

```
function getDirectText(node) {
    var text = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = node.childNodes[i];

        if (child.nodeType === 3) {  // Node.TEXT_NODE
            text += child.nodeValue;
        }
    }

    return text;
}
```

and then:

```
var text = getText(document.getElementsByClassName('classDiv')[0]);
```

You might want to trim the result of whitespace, too.

Comment: I got distracted while writing my own answer, wandered off to come back and find yours; since my own answer and yours are only marginally different it seems pointless adding my own, so if you consider this a useful alternative I'd be quite happy if you wanted to add it to your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/num9zf3b/ :) (although I chose to return the Array, rather than joining it together.)

Comment: @DavidThomas: I think that stands on its own as a nice ES6 way; if you added it, I’d vote for it. =)