# How to get just <li> text without getting text from other elements inside li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, css-position

I have an `ul` list inside which `li` are there, and inside `li` text and `div` are there. `same` class is assigned to `li` while `div` are assigned with different class name.

I just want to get the text from `li` and not from `div`.
Here is the snippet:

```js
$("ul li").on('click', function() {
  $("span").text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
ul {
  position: relative
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='same'>Text1
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <li class='same'>Text2
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <li class='same'>Text3
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <span> </span>
```

I get the O/P, but also text inside div come how to avoid that ?

Comment: A (not very nice) alternative to using `nodeType==3` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063408/how-to-get-text-only-from-the-div-when-it-has-child-elements-with-text-using-jqu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get text node of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/get-text-node-of-an-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter out the *text nodes* from the `li` - see demo below:

```js
$("ul li").on('click', function() {
  $("span").text($(this).contents().filter(function(){
      return this.nodeType == 3; // select text nodes
  }).text()); // paste all of them to the span
});
```

```css
ul {
  position: relative
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='same'>Text1
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <li class='same'>Text2
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div> and more
  </li>
  <li class='same'>Text3
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  </ul>
    <span> </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [**TextNode Object**](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkuedch.php).

Plain JavaScript properties:

- [**.firstChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)
- [**.nodeValue**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue)

If you do mix plain JavaScript with jQuery remember to [**dereference the jQuery object**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533784/2813224) you intend to use plain JavaScript on by using:

Bracket Notation:

`$(Object)[0]`

or

`.get()` method:

`$(Object).get(0)`

**Details commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
$("ul li").on('click', function() {
  /* Dereference $(this) by adding [0]
  || $(this)[0] = this
  || Now plain JavaScript methods and properties...
  ||...can be used.
  */
  /*
  || this.firstChild
  || .firstChild property will return the first node
  || A node can be an element, a comment, text, or...
  ||...even whitespace.
  || see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node
  || The firstChild of any <li> is "Text1", "Text2", 
  || or "Text3"
  */
  /*
  || this.firstChild.nodeValue
  || .nodeValue will return a node as a string
  */
  $("span").text($(this)[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
});
```

```css
ul {
  position: relative
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='same'>Text1
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <li class='same'>Text2
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <li class='same'>Text3
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <span> </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text() to get the text of outer element

```js
$("ul li").on('click', function() {
  $("span").text($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text());
});
```

```css
ul {
  position: relative
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='same'>Text1
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <li class='same'>Text2
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <li class='same'>Text3
    <div class='notsame'>Other text</div>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <span> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

My prefered solution is to create a clone of the element in the memory, and  remove it's children before reading it's content.

In your case:

```
$( "ul li" ).on( 'click' , function() {

   $( "span" ).text( $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text() );

});
```

I recommend this solution because it's a one-liner.

Comment: hi @Steven, how to change the text of that ?

Comment: @jafarpinjar How to change the text of what? :)

Comment: this line give the text of li, but after getting that text, I need to replace with some text